# How to uninstall ProdDialog/15.4.0+26906.3206.a.prodiag from VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to install the [Snapshot Debugger extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-applications) in VS2017 latest preview, for set snappoints and logpoints against apps running in Azure App Services.

I installed visual studio 2017 preview(2) in my local machine, see below screenshot:

[image]

But whenever I run **SnapshotDebugger.vsix** file it gives the error like below:

[image]

So, can you please tell me how to resolve this error as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you install certain extension in your VS IDE before? the Snapshot Debugger is only available for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version, I can install it in my VS2017 Enterprise version 15.3.5, click help menu->about VS, would you please share me the detailed VS version information with a screen shot? I will test it in my side, at least, we could know that whether it was the version issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I installed VS2017 Preview(2) with version of 15.4.0 Preview 3.0 from this link https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes

Comment: I setup the preview version, but I could install it in my side: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SnapshotDebuggerTeam.MicrosoftSnapshotDebugger, so I think it was not the version issue, we would think about the specific VS Environment, did you install certain extension tool after you installed the VS in your side which was called/related to ProdDialog/15.4.0+26906.3206.a.prodiag or others? Maybe you could disable or remove the extension, view the result. Please try to install/disable extensions from extension and update windows under TOOLS menu, view the result.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I didn't install this extension earlier ProdDialog/15.4.0+26906.3206.a.prodiag and I check in extensions and updates in that there is no extension available related ProdDialog/15.4.0+26906.3206.a.prodiag.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, can you please try to install snapshot debugger extension from this link http://aka.ms/snapshotdebuggervsix

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I am able to install Visual Studio Snapshot Debugger extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SnapshotDebuggerTeam.MicrosoftSnapshotDebugger but  before installing this extension I am trying to install snapshot debugger extension from this link http://aka.ms/snapshotdebuggervsix, then it gives the error like ProdDialog/15.4.0+26906.3206.a.prodiag contains older packages. so, can you please what is the difference between both extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed as of Visual Studio 2017 15.4 Preview 4. You can use the Visual Studio Installer to update your VS Preview install to Preview 4, then install the Snappoints and Logpoints vsix from https://aka.ms/snapshotdebuggervsix

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue if I install the same package showed by you. So it was related to the extension package you got.

One extension here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SnapshotDebuggerTeam.MicrosoftSnapshotDebugger

We could install it, but it has different steps shared by you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger

**Update:**

I report this issue to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/122117/snapshot-debugger-not-work.html

You could add your comment and vote it.

Comment: I installed above extension successfully but when ever I connected to azure production app service for debugging it doesn't show the Attach Snapshot Debugger option.

Comment: I followed the below link to Debug live ASP.NET apps using snappoints and logpoints https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-applications

Comment: @pradeep, You are right, they are really different. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger. But I will report this issue to the product team for the  Snapshot Debugger extension.

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for resolving this issue by Microsoft team.

Comment: Edit the answer, and post the feedback link, you could vote and add your comment there:)